# Reading a file in java with multiple fields

Tags: java, mysql

I have a 10,000(txt file) record file that needs to be loaded into MySQL DB. I'm planning to write a Java program to read the file and write into DB.

About the file:

The file has 30 fields of varying field types, Ex:- String, int, double, char..

Currently, I'm planning to read the file into a String array and extract the data. Example code given below..(String is assumed to be a record from a line)

```
public class Read {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s ="Bob&&01-01-1980&&20&&CA";
        String[] a1= s.split("&&");
        System.out.println(a1[0]);
        String name = a1[0];
        String dob = a1[1];
        String age = a1[2];
        String state = a1[3];
        System.out.println(name + " " + dob + " " + age +" " + state);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to extract data from a file with 30-40 fields?

Comment: a FILE has no "fields" whatsoever, you're mixing up quite a few things here

Comment: You could try creating a POJO and a builder (or a factory) and create a `List` of your Java Objects.

Comment: @specializt: The file I have has a delimiter '&&'

Comment: files have no "delimiter" except for maybe EOF, BOM and the likes - and these are no real delimiters, they're boundary-indicators, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach looks fine to me. With 10k rows, you probably need to do a `COMMIT` every hundred rows or so. If you're importing to a MyISAM table, you don't need to worry about that.

If I were doing this project, I'd use MS Excel (which I happen to have handy) or Open Office's spreadsheet program to import the text file to a spreadsheet. I'd then inspect the spreadsheet to make sure everything was clean, then export it as a .csv file. Finally, I'd use the [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlimport.html) utility program to load the csv file into MySQL. That procedure would probably handle various syntax edge-cases more reliably than a bespoke Java program.

On the other hand, if this was to be a weekly load job, the Java program would be the way to go.

(Of course && is a legitimate delimiter. mysqlimport calls it `fields_terminated_by` .)

Answer (score 0):

Since you said your file has a delimiter, it would be easier to use MySQL's built in method to import this data:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

just use fields terminated by '&&'

This will also only use one connection to the db, so it will consume less RAM and be faster than using java code.